# REACT Passing an object as props in a component is consoleloged, but the values are undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I try to pass an object sujets as a props to a component SujetsProvider (which then provide a context to a header component).
in the component SujetsProvider, i can console.log(sujets) but i can't console.log the values inside sujets, they are undefined

**the object**

```
sujets = {
  B1_logique: 0,
  B2_accueil: 0,
  B3_prise_en_charge: 0,
  B4_questionnement: 0,
  B5_reformulation: 0,
  B6__r_ponse: 0,
  B7_r_actions_client: 0,
  B8_conclusion: 0,
  C1__coute: 0,
...}
```

**Child component**

Child component where I update the sujets object

```
export default function GrilleSujets() {
  const [sujets, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  function reducer(sujets, action) {...}


// Event Handler for updating sujets via reducer
  const handleClick = function (val) {
    dispatch({ type: val });
  };
```

I pass the props sujets to the component SujetProvider

```
return (
    <StyledGrille>
      <SujetsProvider sujets={sujets} />
      {/* SAVOIR FAIRE */}
      <Bloc variation="savoir_faire" size="medium" area="SAVOIR_FAIRE">
        SAVOIR FAIRE
      </Bloc>
      <Bloc
        variation="savoir_faire"
        size="medium"
        area="LP_Accueil_du_client_Valeur"
        background={back(sujets.LP_Accueil_du_client_Valeur)}
        onClick={() => handleClick("LP_Accueil_du_client_Valeur")}
      >
        Accueil
      </Bloc>
```

I receive the props in SujetsProvider and provide the object sujets to the context

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
const SujetsContext = createContext({});
function SujetsProvider({ sujets, children }) {
  console.log(sujets);
  const val = "Hello World";

  return (
    <SujetsContext.Provider value={{ sujets: sujets, exemple: val }}>
      {children}
    </SujetsContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useSujets() {
  const context = useContext(SujetsContext);
  // if (context.sujets === undefined)
  //   throw new Error("SujetsContext est utilisé en dehors de SujetsProvider");
  console.log(context);
  return context;
}

export { SujetsProvider, useSujets };
```

I route via ReactRouter in  App

```
import Sujets from "./pages/Sujets";
import Pratiques from "./pages/Pratiques";
import PageNotFound from "./pages/PageNotFound";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Account from "./pages/Account";
import Settings from "./pages/Settings";
import Users from "./pages/Users";
import Entrainements from "./pages/Entrainements";
import AppLayout from "./ui/AppLayout";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<Navigate replace to="dashboard" />} />
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="entrainements" element={<Entrainements />} />
            <Route path="pratiques" element={<Pratiques />} />
            <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
            <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />} />
            <Route path="account" element={<Account />} />
            <Route path="sujets" element={<Sujets />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

I englobe Applayout with the context via SujetsProvider

```
export default function AppLayout() {
  return (
    <SujetsProvider>
      <StyledAppLayout>
        <Header />
        <Sidebar />
        <Main>
          <Outlet />
        </Main>
      </StyledAppLayout>
    </SujetsProvider>
  );
}
```

// I consume the context in Header

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useSujets } from "./sujets/SujetsContextProvider";

const StyledHeader = styled.header`
  background-color: var(--color-grey-0);
  padding: 1.2rem 4.8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-grey-100);`
;

function Header() {
  // const { theme, exemple } = useSujets();
  const { sujets, exemple } = useSujets();
  console.log(sujets);
  console.log(`header ${exemple}`);
  return (
    <StyledHeader>
      Header {sujets} {exemple}
    </StyledHeader>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

but sujets in Header keeps being undefined, the rest of the context ("Hello World") is correctly passed to Header

when i go back to the first props passing in SujetsProvider, i can console.log(sujets) and see the object sujets in the console
but I cannot console.log(sujets.B1_Logique) which is undefined

in the console i see the full object sujets, but when I console.log(sujets.B1_Logique) which the first key of sujets, I receive:@react-refresh:278 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'B1_Logique')
at SujetsProvider (SujetsContextProvider.jsx:6:22)

Thank you very much for your help

I tried another method: to lift sujets until App via prodrilling a new state (sujetRef) but could not find a working method

I have also tried in SujetsProvider

```
const sujets2 = this.props.sujets;
  console.log(sujets2);
```

but I receive Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
at SujetsProvider (SujetsContextProvider.jsx:6:24)

I add the reducer which is in GrilleSujets:

```
 function reducer(sujets, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "LP_Accueil_du_client_Valeur":
        if (sujets.LP_Accueil_du_client_Valeur === 1)
          return { ...sujets, LP_Accueil_du_client_Valeur: -1 };
        else
          return {
            ...sujets,
            LP_Accueil_du_client_Valeur: sujets.LP_Accueil_du_client_Valeur + 1,
          };
      case "LP_D_couverte_des_Attentes_du_Client_Valeur":
        if (sujets.LP_D_couverte_des_Attentes_du_Client_Valeur === 1)
          return {
            ...sujets,
            LP_D_couverte_des_Attentes_du_Client_Valeur: -1,
          };
        else
          return {
            ...sujets,
            LP_D_couverte_des_Attentes_du_Client_Valeur:
              sujets.LP_D_couverte_des_Attentes_du_Client_Valeur + 1,
          }; ...
```

and InitialState which is in GrilleSujets as well

```
const initialState = {
  B1_logique: 0,
  B2_accueil: 0,
  B3_prise_en_charge: 0,
  B4_questionnement: 0,
  B5_reformulation: 0,
  B6__r_ponse: 0,
  B7_r_actions_client: 0,
  B8_conclusion: 0,
  C1__coute: 0,
  C2_proximit: 0,
  LP_Accueil_du_client_Valeur:0,
...
```

here is the component tree:
[component tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYMOZ.png)

Comment: It sounds like something mutated it incorrectly. Show us the whole reducer implementation including where `initialState` is from. There's something suspicious about `dispatch({ type: val });` since `type` is usually the action type and not the payload and that makes me wonder about the reducer impl.

Comment: In `AppLayout` you are not passing any `sujets` prop to `SujetsProvider`.

Comment: thank you Drew, I have added an extract of the reducer and of initialState in the post,  and also an image of the component tree

Comment: thank adsy also

Comment: Apparently GrilleSujets pass correctly the props sujets in SujetsProvider because i can consolelogit with all its values in SujetsProvider,  it is when I want to access to the values, that it is undefined. And context API is working fine as well because I can print in Header the object passed ("Hello World") from SujetsProvider

Comment: You still are not passing any `sujets` prop to the `SujetsProvider` in the `AppLayout` component. That's all you need to do here, pass a `sujets` prop to `SujetsProvider` and it will pass passed though on the provided React Context.

Comment: You are right Drew, but I could not lift up the state `sujets` to `AppLayout`  and pass it to `SujetsProvider`, it created an infinite loop. Eventually I create a useRef hook `sujetsRef` ,pass it to `SujetsProvider`  and updated its current state in `GrillesSujets`  thru eventhandler `const handleClick = function (val) {
    dispatch({ type: val });
    sujetsRef.current = sujets;
    console.log(sujetsRef);
  };`  it works, thak you for your help, have a nice day

Comment: Drew, how do I choose your answer to highlight it ?